# What timezone is googlefit data stored in

Tags: google-fit

I'm trying to figure out how to 'normalize' the display of steps for a day across timezones and I haven't found anything in the api docs that indicates if a user's data is stored by the user's timezone or if it stored by GMT (which would be grand).  The rest call we are using to get steps for a timeframe is:

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps/datasets/

Thanks in advance for any insight

Comment: This sounds like it would be appropriate to ask of Google support rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah..I looked through the help / support for googlefit and they send us here.

Comment: I meant more along the lines of 'contact them to get in touch with a person', not 'read their support pages'.

Comment: I don't understand what "'normalize' the display of steps for a day across timezones" means; but the answer to your title question is: it's not stored in any time zone, it's stored as nanos or millis (depending on the field) since Unix epoch.

Comment: Makes sense..epoch is utc..I'll test some more..

Comment: Guys I have same problem, want to know how to get timezone info from GoogleFit Android API, at least to know how Google fit API stores timezone info? any news please cover up this info, if you have any.